# Как правильно подключить к проекту Yii2 виджет yii\jui\DatePicker?

Tags: yii2, yii, виджет, yii-bootstrap

Решил подключить к проекту виджет yii\jui\DatePicker http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-jui-datepicker.html

Добавил в composer.json (как это сказано в документации https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-jui к виджету) строку:

```
...
"yiisoft/yii2-jui": "~2.0.0"
...
```

Обновилcя:

```
composer update
```

Добавил в шаблон дизайна код:

```
<?php

echo \yii\jui\DatePicker::widget( [ 'name'  => 'from_date', 'value'  => '', 'language' => 'ru' ] );

?>
```

В результате на странице появился input:

```
<input type="text" id="w0" name="from_date" value="">
```

А так же появился JS-код:

```
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function () {
$('#w0').datepicker($.extend({}, $.datepicker.regional['ru'], {"dateFormat":"M d, yy"}));
});</script>
```

DatePicker не заработал... И в консоли выводится ошибка:

> jquery.js:3793 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'regional' of
>   undefined

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все ли скрипты подключились? 

`<script src="/web/assets/6979d031/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/web/assets/ac9a3336/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="/web/assets/ac9a3336/ui/i18n/datepicker-ru.js"></script>`

Comment: Да, эти скрипты присутствуют

Comment: В правильном порядке, и после них js с вызовом datepicker? Просто ошибка говорит о том что `$.datepicker` не существует. То есть или нет  `jquery-ui` на странице, или еще не загружен. Или у вас дубликат `jquery.js`, возможно вы на странице где то в ручную подключаете jquery.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример с моего проекта. Я думаю у Вас ошибка в параметре `language`, должно быть `ru-RU`.

```
<?php
    use yii\jui\DatePicker;

    echo $form->field($model, 'birthdate')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
        'language' => 'ru-Ru',
        'dateFormat' => 'yy-MM-dd',
        'clientOptions' => [ 
            'yearRange' => '1956:2016',
            'changeMonth' => 'true',
            'changeYear' => 'true',
            'firstDay' => '1',
        ]
    ]);
?>
```